# Django CMS isnot in admin page, why?

Tags: content-management-system, django-admin

[image]i followed all steps in this docs: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.3/getting_started/tutorial.html#configuration-and-setup

and everything is working fine, but in admin page i dont see `cms` block where i can add pages. what could i be missing ?

Comment: You probably didn't add the cms apps to `INSTALLED_APPS` or didn't add `admin.autodiscover()` to your `urls.py`

Comment: i did. here is my urls.py 
http://pastebin.de/27933

Comment: i think this is a python version problem, i have python2.6 and django1.4.

Comment: any ideas how to get this working :( ?

Comment: could you provide your settings.py file?

Comment: here it is: http://pastebin.de/27934

Comment: Does it work if you move the `'django.contrib.admin'` entry in `INSTALLED_APPS` to the end of the tuple? Otherwise did you run the syncdb command?

Comment: i did what you told me: no it is not working.. i found the problem now i think. i changed the place of ``url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),`` to the second place after admin in ``urls.py``. but now it is saying: 
``Reverse for 'cms_page_add' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.``

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13860/discussion-between-doniyor-and-ulrich-dangel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you have solved this, but I had the same problem: I mistyped plugin_pool.register_plugin(MyPlugin) and that made "CMS>Pages" section disappear in the admin. Maybe you have something wrong in your cms_plugins.py file too. Something similar happened to me when I tried to use {% extend some_variable %} instead of {% extend "base.html" %} in my template. I hope it helps

Comment: hey Alessio, thanks for answer, i havenot solved the problem yet, as for your answer: is it also possible that there are mistypes in the docs of cms? i did nothing new i just installed as shown in the doc, you mean, i should also check for some syntax errors in the plugin?

Comment: I meant if you have some error in the file where you define your custom plugins (I was trying to register a non-existing plugin), it's likely that you'll get a silent error and the CMS section will not show in the admin. It happened to me twice with different errors. If it's not your case, the only things that come to my mind now is trying to comment cms.plugins... in INSTALLED_APPS, or trying different versions of mptt (that caused some problems during startup, but no idea if it has something to do with this)

Comment: oh okay, great let me then try this also, i thought first that django version and cms version are not coming along with each other well... but i dont know the clue still..

Comment: hey man, i solved the problem by installing cmsplugin_filer manually but i dont know what the real problem was.. anyway. thanks for attempt to help..

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, maybe commenting the filer line in INTALLED_APPS also made the problem disapper? It's interesting to notice which different kind of problems lead to these hard-to-correct silent errors